# Why is "Don't do such stupid things" unnatural?

Tags: determiners, formality

I talked to two native speakers of English, and they did not say anything was wrong with the following sentence:

> 1. Don't do stupid shit.

But they said that the following sentence is not natural.  They said they don't usually use it unless they want to keep the vibe that indicates the sentence was translated from Chinese or something:

> 2. Don't do such stupid things.

Why is the second sentence considered as unnatural to native?

Comment: What makes you think it is unnatural? Any references for that?

Comment: @Lambie Two natives people I met today said like that. They said they don't usually use it unless they want to keep the vibe that indicates the sentences was translated from Chinese or something. Unfortunately I didn't have a chance to ask back because of some other reasons.

Comment: Those people do not know what they were talking about. This is not worth discussing. Sorry.

Comment: This issue certainly is worth discussing, but it lacks the necessary context / detail / intended meaning to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example sentence #2 contains contradictory levels of formality.

"Such" is a formal word, especially when it is used as a determiner.  It is used in formal contexts, such as textbooks and contracts.  "Such as" is not as formal as the use of "such" in the example sentence.

Contractions are informal.

"Stupid things" is an informal phrase.